# How to replace the array

Tags: c

```
 for (letter = 'a', exponent = 0; letter <= 'z'; letter++, exponent++) {
        int result = pow(2, exponent);
        str[exponent] = result;
       }
```

I have a task in which I have letters from a to z and to each letter is assigned a number a = 2^0 b = 2^1 and so on, I wrote it through a loop and I do not know how to write them to use them in the future code, if you use an array, the task becomes twice as difficult.

Comment: What's wrong with your code?  It looks more or less correct. Could you post a [mcve]? That being said, don't use ever the `pow` function for powers of two when you do integer calculations, use `1 << exponent` instead of `pow(2, exponent)`. But anyway from your descriptions it's pretty unclear what you're asking...

Comment: If you use Jabberoky's method, you probably don't benefit much from a lookup table.  You can turn a `char c` into a power of 2 very efficiently with `1 << (c-'a')`.  This works because the letters `a` to `z` are consecutive in ASCII.  (which really shines a light on how stupid this assignment is, because letters `a` to `z` are *already* assigned a number under ASCII, and it only takes *one* byte to store any of the ascii letters , numbers, etc, and in the assignment z is 2^25 for which you'll need a `uint32_t`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading your question several times I guess you want something like  this:

```
int YourFunction(char letter)
{
  return 1 << (letter - 'a');
}
```

`1 << n` is `2` to the power of `n`, or in other words `1` shifted `n` times to the left. Read about the `<<` operator in your C text book.

A complete example might look like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

// letter to binary
uint32_t ltob(char c) {
  return (c < 'a' || c > 'z') ? 0 : (uint32_t)1 << ( c - 'a' );
}

int main() {
  for( char c = 'a'; c <= 'z'; c++) {
    printf("%c, %08x\n", c, ltob(c));
  }
}
```

Which outputs: (keep in mind the outputs are in hex as C does not natively support output in base2):

```
a, 00000001
b, 00000002
c, 00000004
d, 00000008
e, 00000010
f, 00000020
g, 00000040
h, 00000080
i, 00000100
j, 00000200
k, 00000400
l, 00000800
m, 00001000
n, 00002000
o, 00004000
p, 00008000
q, 00010000
r, 00020000
s, 00040000
t, 00080000
u, 00100000
v, 00200000
w, 00400000
x, 00800000
y, 01000000
z, 02000000
```

Disclaimer:  this only works on platforms which use the ASCII character set and, but it's very, very unlikely that your platform doesn't, so you don't really bother about this.

Comment: @erik258 no problem